# Let $S$ be a set and $p$ a prime number and $m\in N$ such that $p$ does not divide $m$. Show $p$ does not divide $|S|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm currently doing an exercise where this should be shown:

Let $S$ be a set and $p$ a prime number and $m\in N$ such that $p$ does not divide $m$.

Suppose $|S| = p^rm(p^rm-1)...(p^rm-p^r+1)/{p^r(p^r-1)...1}$ is the size of $S$.

Show $p$ does not divide $|S|$.

Could someone tell me why this is true ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in fact

$$|S|=\frac{m(p^rm-1)(p^rm-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p^rm-p^r+1)}{(p^r-1)(p^r-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}$$

Now just prove the easy

$$\forall\;k\in\Bbb N\,,\,1\le k\le p^r-1\;;\;\;p\mid(p^rm-k)\iff p\mid (p^r-k)$$

and deduce that $\;|S|\;$ has no factor equal to any non-zero positive power of $\;p\;$ .

Comment: To divide, $p$ must both divide the numerator and denominator, why?

Comment: @DonAntonio : you need something a little stronger - the power of $p$ dividing $(p^rm-k)$ is the same as that dividing $(p^r - k)$ [This is also true, of course]

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen : He just means that the powers of $p$ appearing the top and bottom cancel each other out (term by term)

Comment: Indeed so, @PrahladVaidyanathan, yet the one follows from the other: just take one power at a time.

Comment: I dont see why they cancel each other out :-(

Comment: The only way I can see how to proof this is by contradiction:
Suppose $p$ divides $|S|$ then $p$ must divide $|S|(p^r-1)(p^r-2)...1$ and $m(p^rm-1)(p^rm-2)...(p^rm-p^r+1)$. However $p$ does not divide $m(p^rm-1)(p^rm-2)...(p^rm-p^r+1)$ since it does not divide one of its factors. Hence a contradiction that $p$ divides $|S|$ ?

Comment: However why does $(p^rm-1)$ and $(p^r-1)$ cancel each other out ?

Comment: Of course they don't, @NicolasLykkeIversen ! What cancels out is each and every power of $\;p\;$ that divides one *also* divides the other one, so there's no left any fator $\;p\;$ at the end...

Comment: And of course $\;p\;$ may divide one of the factors of that product you wrote, @NicolasLykkeIversen, for example $$p\mid (p^rm-p)\;,\;p\mid (p^rm-2p)\;,\;\text{and etc.}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand it now.